# U-SQL Substring out of range exception

Tags: substring, azure-data-lake, u-sql, outofrangeexception

We are trying to publish data from a table using U-SQL in ADLA. We are using below code to get substring for FirstName, as we want to restrict the length of FirstName to 50 characters.

```
SELECT (firstName == null || firstName.Length <= 50) ? firstName : firstName.Substring(0, 50) AS FirstName
```

But, we are getting below error:

> E_RUNTIME_USER_EXPRESSION_EVALUATION >
>   E_RUNTIME_USER_SUBSTRING_OUT_RANGE

When we tried to perform substring using custom .NET Code, we are not getting exception. The job is completing successfully. We are not getting any error rows.

```
public static string DoSubString(string firstName)
        {
            string subFirstName;

            try
            {
                subFirstName = (firstName == null || firstName.Length <= 50) ? firstName : firstName.Substring(0, 50);

            }
            catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException ae)
            {
                subFirstName = string.Format("Argument Out of range Error {0} {1}",firstName,ae.Message);
            }
            catch(Exception Ex)
            {
                subFirstName = string.Format("Generic Error {0} {1}",firstName, Ex.Message); 
            }

            return subFirstName;

        }
```

We are not able to find out the error row. When we look into Profile.xml, we are not getting row dump.

> Inner exception from user expression: \nCurrent row
>   dump: "

How to find out the error row causing this exception? How to troubleshoot these kinds of issues ?

Comment: David's answer works and it is often difficult to find out why you are getting the error without a repro. Can you please provide a sample script that repros the error? I can only guess right now why it may try to execute the `Substring` method on a value that is shorter. Alternatively, file an incident, since the expression definitively looks valid.

Comment: Sure Micheal. Will do. thanks for your inputs.

Comment: we filed incident and got the response. I have added that to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We raised an issue with product group. It seems there is some problem with the substring operation in U-SQL. They asked us to apply the below fix for Substring calculation. We tried it and it is working properly.

```
SELECT (firstName == null || firstName.Length <= 50) ? firstName : firstName.Substring(0, Math.Min(firstName.Length, 50)) AS FirstName
```

Answer (score 2):

For testing I used 10 characters, revise for 50.

```
@table = 
SELECT * FROM 
    ( VALUES
    ("appleJackss"),
    ("apple Jacks"),
    ("appleJacks"),
    ("                 "),
    (""),
    ((string)null)
    ) AS T(word);

@result = 
SELECT  //Method 1
        CASE
            WHEN word.Length <= 10 THEN word
            ELSE word.Substring(0, 10)
        END AS justTen,

        // Method 2
        (word.Length <= 10) ? word : word.Substring(0, 10) AS anotherTen
FROM @table;

OUTPUT @result
TO "/Temp/Example1.txt"
USING Outputters.Tsv();
```

Comment: Thanks David. The expression I provided works for many times. But, sometimes due to data issues, we are facing this substring error. Want to find out, which row causes this issues. I will try the CASE logic also, as you have suggested.

Comment: I tried with CASE logic, still the same error. I want to troubleshoot the data row, which is causing this issue.